# QAbstractTabelModel.data() always getting index.row() == 0 and only shows 1 row

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside2, qabstracttablemodel

I have defined my custom `QAbstrtactTableModel` in python and implemented `columnCount()`, `rowCount()`, `data()` and `headerData()` and also added a function to `add()` new entries:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QProcess, Signal,\
    Slot, QObject, QThread, Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex,\
    QTimer
import random


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, values):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)

        self.values = values

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.values)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        print("called")
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                print(index.row())
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return list(self.values.keys())[index.row()]
                else:
                    return self.values[list(self.values.keys())[index.row()]]

    def add(self, data):
        self.values[data[0]] = data[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                if section == 0:
                    return "Parking,Meter"
                elif section == 1:
                    return "Revenue"


class Monitor(QObject):
    data_batch_ready = Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Monitor, self).__init__(parent)

    @Slot(list)
    def fill_batch(self):
        my_data = []
        for parking in range(4):
            for index in range(10):

                my_data.append([str(parking)+","+str(index), random.randint(1,101)])
        self.data_batch_ready.emit(my_data)


class Gui(QMainWindow):
    system_process = QProcess()
    parking_model = TableModel(values={"0,0": "0"})

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        file = QFile("minimal.ui")
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

        loader = QUiLoader()
        ui = loader.load(file)
        self.setCentralWidget(ui)

        self.centralWidget().parking_table.setModel(self.parking_model)

    @Slot(list)
    def update_gui_revenue(self, data):
        print("fire")
        for row in data:
            self.parking_model.add(row)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Gui()
    gui.show()

    thread = QThread()
    moni = Monitor()
    timer = QTimer(moni)
    timer.setInterval(1)
    moni.moveToThread(thread)
    moni.data_batch_ready.connect(gui.update_gui_revenue, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    timer.timeout.connect(moni.fill_batch, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    thread.started.connect(timer.start)
    thread.started.connect(lambda: print("time started"))
    thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The data is a python dictionary that is being modified by calling a random function that fills the dictionary with 1 entry every 1 second as follows:

"0,0":[random value]
"0,1":[random value]
"0,2":[random value]
"1,0":[random value]
"1,1":[random value]
"1,2":[random value]

`rowCount()` correctly reflects the number of rows in the data `values`, but the `tableView` only displays 1 row all the time and the `data()` is only requesting `index.row() == 0`

EDIT: added `timer.setInterval(1)`

Comment: please show a workable code.

Comment: @eyllanesc code: https://pastebin.com/ZAHfbGLU

Comment: please shate `minimal.ui`

Comment: it's one `TableView` called parking_table, do you want the actual file?

Comment: minimal.ui: https://pastebin.com/6iS1a9VN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models can not monitor when a data is modified if you do not notify it, for which in your case there are 2 types of modifications, the first is the row insertion and the other is the update. For the insertion of rows you must use the `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` methods, and for the second you must notify by launching the `dataChanged` signal.

On the other hand, do not make the model variable in the class, you have to make it a variable of the instance.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools
import random


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, values={}, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.values = values

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid(): return 0
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid(): return 0
        return len(self.values)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return list(self.values.keys())[index.row()]
                else:
                    return self.values[list(self.values.keys())[index.row()]]

    def add(self, data):
        key, value = data 
        if key in self.values:
            row = list(self.values.keys()).index(key)
            self.values[key] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(row, 1), self.index(row, 1))
        else:
            self.add_row(key, value)

    def add_row(self, key, value):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.values[key] = value
        self.endInsertRows()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section == 0:
                    return "Parking,Meter"
                elif section == 1:
                    return "Revenue"


class Monitor(QtCore.QObject):
    data_batch_ready = QtCore.Signal(list)

    @QtCore.Slot(list)
    def fill_batch(self):
        my_data = []
        for parking in range(4):
            for index in range(10):
                my_data.append([str(parking)+","+str(index), random.randint(1,101)])
        self.data_batch_ready.emit(my_data)


class Gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        file =QtCore.QFile("minimal.ui")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.parking_model = TableModel(values={"0,0": "0"}, parent=self)

        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        ui = loader.load(file)
        self.setCentralWidget(ui)

        self.centralWidget().parking_table.setModel(self.parking_model)

    @QtCore.Slot(list)
    def update_gui_revenue(self, data):
        for row in data:
            self.parking_model.add(row)


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Gui()
    gui.show()

    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    moni = Monitor()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(moni)
    timer.setInterval(10)
    moni.moveToThread(thread)
    moni.data_batch_ready.connect(gui.update_gui_revenue, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    timer.timeout.connect(moni.fill_batch, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    thread.started.connect(timer.start)
    thread.started.connect(lambda: print("time started"))
    thread.start()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(thread.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I thought `dataChanged()` needs to be called if `setData()` is being used, but it makes perfect sense here, basically any data modification has to call it.